# java MouseListener and MouseAdapter - pass in variable

Tags: java, listener

i have the following method:

```
public static void createDialog(Button b, String message)
{
    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(mouseEvent)) {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                        "mymessage", "mymessage", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I want to be able to get the parameter message, into the JOptionPane where is says mymessage. Is there a way to do this?

I can't access any variables from inside the class that are outside. Is there a way to get that value in there? I would eventually like to get a few other parameters in there as well.

Thanks!

Comment: "I can't access any variables from inside the class that are outside."  Why?  Are you resistent to declaring your variables/parameters `final`?

Comment: nope, not resistant, just ignorant of the possibility I guess... thank GOD you were there to set me strait!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't access any variables from inside the class that are outside.

Not in general, but you *can* access final variables, so just put `final` in front of the `String message` parameter:

```
public static void createDialog(Button b, final String message) {
    //                                    ^^^^^
    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(mouseEvent)) {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                        message, message, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: +1 Works like a charm! You answered so fast I have to wait 10 more minutes to mark it

Comment: Great job. Worked like a charm